# User password reset - redirect one time login to another page

Tags: users, forms

By default, if user submit his email in form at `/user/password` page, he will recieve an email with one-time login link. After opening this link he is redirected to page with form with one single "login" button - id of this form is `user_pass_reset`. After click on this button user is redirected to his profile in administrative part of a site: `/user/X/edit` where he can change his password.

But I have my own custom profile page, where users can change their password and I'd like to redirect user here instead of default profile in administration interface. I already found that `user` module is checking if old password is needed with this line:

```
$pass_reset = isset($_SESSION['pass_reset_' . $account->uid]) && isset($_GET['pass-reset-token']) && ($_GET['pass-reset-token'] == $_SESSION['pass_reset_' . $account->uid]);
```

But I can't find out how to redirect user to my own form on `user_pass_reset` submit. If I alter this form and change `'#action'` paramter I get a message that says this one-time login link is invalid. If I add my own submit function `$form['#submit'][] = 'activit_password_redirect';` and in this function I call `drupal_goto('my/own/form/page')` user is still redirected to default profile page.

Is it possible to change url of this form submit?

Answer (score 1):

Use hook_form_alter, then add a  $form['#redirect'] parameter with value as your custom user profile page.

OR
 append a **destination** query to the default form action url.

```
<default_action_url>?destination=<your_custom_user_profile_url>
```

I recommend the first option. It's the Drupal way.

Comment: It does not work... user module is redirecting to default profile page in submit handler by drupal_goto() function - line 142 of user.pages.inc file

Comment: @Incredible , then you can override it by specifying custom function as you created $form['#submit'][] = 'activity_password_redirect'; , then add change this $form_state['#redirect'] value there.

Comment: I've tryed it but it does nothing.

Comment: @Incredible , this method worked for me. Might be some minor issues, I can't say more until I get know how you implemented it.

Comment: I was exploring user module and found that it has no any submit function in `$form['#submit']` array. It has only `#action` with some url that is calling `pass_reset()` function. In this function is called `drupal_goto()`. I wonder if another submit callbacks can be triggered if there is drupal_goto called before the callbacks.

Comment: @Incredible , drupal_goto() won't work in this scenario. Have you tried to alter the action URL by appending a URL query like   `?destination=my/own/form/page`

Comment: It won't work, because in `pass_reset()` function is drupal_goto() calling specified path: `drupal_goto('user/' . $user->uid . '/edit', array('query' => array('pass-reset-token' => $token)`. I was trying to alter `#action` to my own custom menu item and copy all the code of `pass_reset()` function from user module to my module and change drupal_goto() path to my own path. Maybe I was doing soemthing wrong, but my copied function was not called even if  `#action` was properly altered, instead the original function was called...

Comment: ...So I rewrote drupal_goto() path directly in user module and now it works. I know it's a sin, therefore I'm not posting this solution as an answer. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @Incredible, oh that's too bad... Forgot to mention that there is a hook "hook_user_login"  , one time login link regenerate a session for a user ID after a user clicked on it.  So give a try with that too...